# Showing Drawer on touch video

Tags: java, android

I would like to show navigation drawer when i touch screen or the video view.
I have a video list as drawer item and the video view is fullscreen.
this is video view layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/view"
android:clickable="true"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_new_video"
tools:context="com.rockers.ousla.eiptv.VideoActivity">
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/myVideo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and below my code :

```
 vidView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         /*   if (vidView.isPlaying())
            {
                vidView.stopPlayback();
            }
            else {

                vidView.start();
            }*/
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }


            return true;
        }
    });
```

the problem is when i touch the screen the drawer still closed and after many clicks the drawer is opened and closed by selecting video in the list.

Answer (score 0):

In your `xml` set the `android:clickable="true"` on `VideoView`.

```
 vidView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawers();
            } else {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
      return true;
            }


  });
```

**Edit**

In `VideoView` set

```
  android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: the same problem even worse sometimes the drawer still closed

Comment: @Rockers23 means it remain closed?

Comment: YES, it remains closed

Comment: @Rockers23 don't change your code, and try with edited code snippet.

Comment: @Rockers23 like on first click drawer is not opening?

Comment: Yes drawer is not opening

Comment: @Rockers23   add in videoView `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`  & `android:focusable="false"`, may be this fixed the solution.